# javascript input type file required?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php form which has some fields that have been made required before saving the form

For ex.

```
<td><input class="text_area required" type="text" name="new field"
```

There is some javascript also in this form with file name and file upload which I tried to make required also in the .js file

```
newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
newCell.innerHTML = '<input class="filename required" name="filename"        

newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
newCell.innerHTML = '<input type="file" class="new_file required" name="new file"
```

Like the php fields the red outline shows when the field is left empty when trying to save the form. However unlike the php fields, once the filename field is filled and file has been selected, both fields stay red and do not allow the form to save.

So is there another method that should be used in .js files instead of class="required" and how to get the form to save once fields are not empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
ex:

```
<input type="text" name="startdate" id="startday" required/>
```